# get path of last directory used to save in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, directory, save

Most of applications save something in hard drive, the app save last directory url or path in somewhere (i don't know where is this string) , when you close the app or your mac, after that reopen the app and save something else , the app goes to last directory used (if exit) or user's document folder (if dir not exit). some app like final cut pro opens last project that worked in it.
i want get last dir used to save, how can i do in objective-c? i want save new project.
Before saving and creating NSSavePanel , get last used dir to examine if there any project has default name like "new project 1", "new project 2",... to my app determine last file used default name for example "new project 10" and my app suggest "new project 11"

Comment: Any reason you don't just use the NSUserDefaults class to save and/or retrieve the last folder that was used to save for the application?

Comment: thanks for mention that, iam new and it's new for me. can you tell me an example for my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last directory of your own application:

```
NSString* navLastRootDirectory = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"NSNavLastRootDirectory"] stringByExpandingTildeInPath] ;
```

To get the last directory of another application, like TextEdit:

```
NSString* pathToTextEditPreferences = [@"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] ;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToTextEditPreferences] ;
NSDictionary* propertyListData = [NSPropertyListSerialization  propertyListWithData:data  options:NSPropertyListImmutable  format:nil  error:nil  ] ;
NSString* navLastRootDirectory = [[propertyListData objectForKey:@"NSNavLastRootDirectory"] stringByExpandingTildeInPath] ;
```

Comment: thanks for answer is more than i asked, unfortunately they closed this question , i don't know why